# Separate files for class definition and declaration in Java

Tags: java, oop

I'm a C++ programmer currently learning Java and I'm wondering if OOP in Java follows the same principle of separation of class definition and declaration as C++ does, ie. place them both in separate files. I've had a look around the internet, including the Android developer website, and all the code I've come across has the definition and declaration carried out at the same time.

Is this simply one of the difference between development in C++ and development in Java, or are the sources I've been looking at simply doing things that way to limit the complexity of their code for posting on the internet? I have seen declarations and definitions combined in some C++ documentation, though I know it is bad practice to do so.

Comment: Well you have interfaces and their implementation separation in Java.

Comment: What's with everyone and interfaces? That's absolutely not what they are for. Separating a single class into interface and implementation makes no sense: they exist to allow a lightweight form of multiple inheritance, to describe a general behaviour that can be implemented separately. This is different from C++'s separation of definition of a specific class.

Comment: Separating a single class into interface and implementation makes perfect sense when the class is "heavy" and you want an easy way to, for example, create a mock for your testing code. Of course, doing it for very simple classes may be overkill.

Comment: @Viruzzo Agreed. We don't need every class to have a IMyClass and MyClassImpl.

Comment: Quite; the distinction between classes and interfaces in Java has very little in common with that between headers and definitions in C++.

Comment: @Seramme if you need to create a mock you are probably better off making a superclass than an interface, which would force you to modify the original implementation *and* reimplement every method.

Comment: @Viruzzo That's true; this (using abstract classes instead of interfaces) is covered in the article that I have linked in my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a practical reason for separating declaration in C++, and it's to allow source files to be compiled separately. There is no such need in Java (as everything is compiled to bytecode separately), so it isn't allowed.

Comment: Another reason for the separation in C++, as I recall, is that you can give someone your class' public interface without giving them the code. In Java, this metadata is in the `.class` file, so you don't need a separate header.

Comment: @yshavit true, of course; it all comes down to being able to compile without having to include the other classes' source (respectively for perfomance and for security reasons).

Answer (score 5):

**The below answer has been edited heavily based on the comments.**

You do not need to split your class into definition and declaration purely for the compiler's sake, as there is no need for forward declarations in Java (as there is in C++). You may want to split a class definition and declaration into an interface/class pair (or [abstract] class/class pair) due to design requirements, such as:

- Multiple classes implementing a single interface.
- Remote Procedure Calls, where you don't want to expose any of your class dependencies (since they may not be available on the client side)
- Class that is used by other classes, but you don't need/want its full functionality when testing (ex. database access service which you may want to mock in your test code)

However, this is more akin to using a virtual base class and concrete implementing classes in C++ and is often called "programming to an interface". You can read more about the technique [in this article](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/designprinciples.html) (with some arguments there why you may prefer to use an abstract class instead of an interface as the base). Also, such splitting should be considered carefully; in many cases, splitting a class is just pure overkill and will lead to unnecessary code bloat.

Therefore, the short answer is: you don't need to split the class only for the sake of having forward declaration (which the original question asks), though you may want to do it if there is a design reason to (but this is **not** the equivalent of C++'s header/class file split).

Comment: +1: Use interfaces to separate the contract from the implementation.

Comment: -1: Justified if multiple implementations of MyService are needed; otherwise it's premature abstraction (which is the root of much evil)

Comment: (for the edit) but that behavious is comparable to C++'s pure abstract classes, still not directly related to declaration separation. Understand that the main source of controversy here is the "to achieve similar functionality" part: these functionalities are not directly related!

Comment: @AndrewSpencer even if you have only one implementation it can be useful to introduce an interface, e.g. when the implementation has some dependencies that users shouldn't be required to import. For example, if I have a remote service that depends on - let's say Spring - the client should not have to import Spring just to be able to call that service. All that's needed is the interface and a dependency for the remote call API. And then there are frameworks which just require interfaces, like JEE 5.

Comment: @Thomas you are missing the point: yes, there are cases when interfaces are required and yes, sometimes useful even for a single implementation, but no, this doesn't directly relate to C++'s header files. As for " the implementation has some dependencies that users shouldn't be required to import" what do you mean? Even if you refer only to the interface you *will* require any and all of the implementation's dependencies, even if you load it at runtime.

Comment: @Viruzzo Very valid point, point taken. This was really not the answer to the original question, since as you say these functionalities are not related. I have once again edited the answer, and +1 to your (accepted) answer.

Comment: @Seramme thank you; your edited answer is definitely useful to the OP in an expanded argument.

Comment: @Viruzzo No, if the implementation has dependencies on some framework and the client doesn't them to call a method you don't import those depencies there. Of course if the client is running in the same class loading context as the server you have the dependecy anyways but if there's any chance the client could run in a different class loading context (same JVM or even another JVM) you'd introduce some potentially hard to remove coupling. Consider web applications calling services in a separate EAR where both have their own class loading context.

Comment: @Thomas of course RPC is one of those cases where interfaces are necessary, but I'd say we have left the original intent of the question *waaay* behind.

Comment: @Viruzzo it wasn't _my_ intent to respond to Andrew's comment: "Justified if multiple implementations of MyService are needed; otherwise it's premature abstraction" which is not true, and to your comment "Even if you refer only to the interface you _will_ require any and all of the implementation's dependencies, even if you load it at runtime." which is also not true.

Comment: @Thomas and when isn't it true? RPC is another thing, since what you use is actually a stub.

Comment: @Viruzzo true, in most cases you have stub implementations for those interfaces but from a programming point of view you still have only one implementation as the stubs/proxies are normally auto-generated. In a strict sense you have another implementation here, so you have a point here.

Comment: Just to stay off-topic... We could argue about whether RPC counts as multiple interfaces; but it's easier for me to correct my statement: "It's justified if there are multiple implementations _or other technical imperatives such as RPC_." To be fair (to me), the original question was clearly about whether declarations and definitions should be split systematically. What I was getting at was, interfaces should not be used systematically, but only when they meet an identified need. I guess we all agree about that.

Answer (score 3):

In Java you don't have a choice: the classname is linked to the file name. For a file named `x/y/z/T.java` from the root of your source files, `T.java` **must** look like:

```
package x.y.z;

[some modifiers here] class T {
     // class T here
}
```

There are ways to separate "class definition" from "implementation", the closest to what you have in mind is declaring an interface `I` and having a class `C` implementing `I`. Also consider abstract classes.

An interface has the exact same constraint except you declare an `interface` instead of a `class`. An abstract class is just a class with the `abstract` modifier.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you have one class in one file, i.e. you can't - and don't need to - split classes over multiple files (you can have multiple non-public classes in one file though).

What you can do is use interfaces, i.e. define the interface for a class in one file and implement that interface in a class in another file. If you then distribute the API you just distribute the interface.

Answer (score 0):

There are no header and source files in Java like you have in C++. If you want to separate the class declaration from its implementation, you can define an interface that declares the methods and then create a class that implements the interface.

Comment: Why the downvote? Just because everyone answered the same thing at the same time?

Comment: An awful lot of people don't agree that this is a "wrong" answer.

Comment: I know I do; as for the awful lot of people, they can vote as everyone else.

Comment: @Viruzzo if you vote everyone down, then please explain _why_ you consider the answers wrong.

Comment: I did in the question's comments.

Comment: @Viruzzo I still don't get why Jesper's answer is wrong (and the others too). He said `If you want to separate the class declaration from its implementation, you can define an interface...` - it's the _if you want_ part, a way to do the separation if _wanted_. Not a must!

Comment: @Thomas well of course, why would he be *forced* to separated the declaration in Java? But wait, in C++ he (basically) is!

Comment: @Viruzzo he isn't _forced_ in Java and isn't in C++ either (although there are more reasons in C++ to do the separation). See header only libraries like most of the Boost libraries that have all their code in just header files.

Comment: @Thomas "code in just header files" that's a contradiction; if anything, they could have declarations in source files and no header files, but I strongly doubt it.

Comment: @Viruzzo have a look at the Boost header only libraries.

Comment: @Thomas http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#header-only-libraries pity is that they can do that because (quoting) they "contain templates and inline functions"; this means that they export nothing, so they can work without using a separate header file; this is **far** from the case for most of the applications (this is, after all, a library). The parts of Boost that actually need to compile stuff have separate header files like everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

The separation you write about does not exist in Java. You can separate the method definitions (non static ones) to an `interface`.

Answer (score 0):

No, this kind of separation is not present in java. But look at the interface keyword. you can declare interfaces explicitly!

Comment: I don't understand why -1. The answer is short, but what is wrong?